# How to resize photo upload to exact dimensions with GD Library

Tags: php, gd

I have learned how to resize an image after uploading to server with GD Library.  It works perfect but I need the images to be resized to exactly 180 x 150px.  Depending on the original size of the image it will sometimes be less than 150 or less than 180.  How do I resize the images to be exactly 180px x 150px each time?

PHP Upload Script

```
// Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
// and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information
$fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
$fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
// START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
exit();
} else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
 // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
 echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
 unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
 exit();
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
exit();
}
// END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ----------------------------------------------------
// Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");
// Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
if ($moveResult != true) {
echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
exit();
}
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
// ---------- Include Universal Image Resizing Function --------
include_once("ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php");
$target_file = "uploads/$fileName";
$resized_file = "uploads/resized_$fileName";
$wmax = 180;
$hmax = 151;
ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
// ----------- End Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
// Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes
echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: $fileErrorMsg";
?>
```

PHP Resize Script

```
<?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
$scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
       $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
} else {
       $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
}
$img = "";
$ext = strtolower($ext);
if ($ext == "gif"){ 
  $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
} else if($ext =="png"){ 
  $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
} else { 
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
}
$tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
// imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
?>
```

Comment: You may consider this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362) in regards to the matter. Also, look at this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/imagick-vs-gd). If you can use imagick I would recommend that you do. One big drawback of the GD library (and there are several) is that you cannot natively resize animated GIF's and would require [imagecraft](https://github.com/coldume/imagecraft) or some other separate library.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using, `ak_img_resize`, is explicitly scaling the image (so as not to produce a distorted result):

```
...
$scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
    $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
} else {
    $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
}
...
```

To always resize to exactly 180x150, then replace the above lines with:

```
$w = 180;
$h = 150;
```

Note that this will produce a distorted result, unless the source image has exactly the same width-to-height ratio (1.2).

If you want an undistorted result then you'll need to resize and [crop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php) the excess height or width.